# Using VMWare 4.x SDK with VS2010 or VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, vmware, vmware-sdk

The most recent VMWare SDK is made for VS2005.  The release notes mention that only VS2005 is supported and that version should be used.

http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/

Does anyone know if its possible to use this SDK with vs2008 or vs2010?  What issues would I run into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using the SDK's .Net bindings, built by VMware's included VS 2005 utility, in VS 2008 and now 2010 for quite a while (over 2 years on 2008). I've had no problems using the same .dlls in newer Visual Studio versions.

Comment: I need the DLL's, does that mean I need to run the build script with the old version of Visual Studio?  I have 2008 and 2010 installed but the batch files error out.

Comment: Yes, I had to build the DLL's from within the VS 2005 command prompt - meaning the entry in the start menu under Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 -> Visual Studio Tools rather than the usual command prompt. The build process for the .Net bindings uses a standard WSDL .Net binding generator included with VS 2005.